# Could I broadcast message to device via Thingsboard RPC?

Tags: thingsboard

I read the RPC Call Doc ((https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#rpc-api). I have a question about the request _id. Does it mean I can use it as a broadcast feature for server? Could I implement an OTA function and using broadcast the update message to device via Thingsboard? Should I use the PRC to broadcast the update message?

Comment: Dear Allen, could you finally control devices using RPC? I want to control my devices without thingsboard dashboard.